# NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex strange issue.

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Strange behaviour in `NSMutableArray`.

I've created object and filled it.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
                         initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Before removing it looks like:

```
array   NSMutableArray *    0x1040b5e0
[0] id  0x00088a44 @"1"
[1] id  0x00088a54 @"2"
[2] id  0x00088a64 @"3"
[3] id  0x00088a74 @"4"
```

After removing FIRST element:

```
array   NSMutableArray *    0x1040b5e0
[0] id  0x00000000 
[1] id  0x00088a54 @"2"
[2] id  0x00088a64 @"3"
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: According to your code, object "1" must be removed.. and your code is working correctly.. then what kind of problem you are facing?????

Comment: the "4" is also missing, and element 0 is nil, which is wrong

Comment: @VineetSinghRawat, look a the output. Yes, "1" was removed. But "2" should be first then and "3" should be second and there should still be "4". What he got is a nil object on index 0 followed by "2" and "3" and "4" disappeard. Is that what you would expect from [array removeObjectAtIndex:0]?

Comment: put a break point on the line where you are going to remove the object, in the field where it shows all your objects to the left of the console at the bottom, right click on the array and go print description. see if its any different to those print outs

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. @Fonix: Thank you for your suggestion, I knew you could type the request into the console but that is so much easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using lldb for debugging? Try **gdb** if so.

lldb has known bugs of this nature where it reports the incorrect values of variables during a debug session.

**To change the debugger to gdb:**

1. Click your target in the toolbar
2. Select 'edit schemes'
3. Make sure the 'run' scheme is selected in the pane on the left.
4. Change the 'Debugger' dropdown from lldb to gdb.

Comment: Indeed there are reports that suggest the LLDB debugger has some bugs on older Xcode versions, like 4.3.1. If you can't upgrade (which is always recommended) try using the GDB alternative.

Comment: lldb still has bugs of this nature as of Xcode 4.6, so beware. It's not production ready for serious development (yet).

Comment: NSLog is still your friend as well, and will tell you just as easily what's in the array. Caveman debugging works.

Comment: What the... so glad i found this entry. I had the same issue and I was doubting my basic programming skills already. When I logged the values they were correct even though the debugger was showing me the strange values...

Comment: @David: I could never find 'edit schemes', it might be my version of Xcode is different (4.6.3) or I just don't know what I am doing - entirely possible since I am new at this. Now, if someone could tell me how a method can change the sent array I would be grateful. I finally created a new array in the method and assigned the incoming array to it for modifying. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

your same code is working fine., just clean and build the project. here is my code

```
NSMutableArray *sampleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                         initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", sampleArray);
[sampleArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", sampleArray);
```